# Change background color of the terminal in ipython notebook / jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In ipython notebook / jupyter (3.1.0) in the options of "new" you can open a terminal. In MacOsx 10.8, the default is white letters in dark background.

Question: is there a way to change/configure this?

Answer (score 3):

```
setterm -term linux -back <background_colour> -fore <text_color> -clear
```

from the colors, you can chose from (both fore- and background):

```
black|blue|green|cyan|red|magenta|yellow|white|default
```

Comment: it does set back/fore colours but for characters only, the main background is still black, how to solve this?

Comment: the setterm command works in native terminal, but it sets background for only non-space characters in jupyter terminal